# Execute commands in docker run while running docker in the background

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run a docker container as a background task, and also execute a few commands inside it. When I run:

```
docker run -d --rm --ipc host --net host \
              --privileged --name test5 bash -c 'echo "hi"' docker/getting-started
```

`docker ps` returns empty. `docker ps -a` doesn't show any docker containers started either.

Is there a way to keep the docker container running in the background, and execute the commands after it starts? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
docker run -d --rm --ipc host --net host \
  --privileged --name test5 bash \
  -c "sleep 30000" docker/getting-started
```

---

```
Docker PS

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE    COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS      NAMES
c3fa4e4522a2   bash     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes              test5
```

**Note 1:** Your container immediately stops unless the commands ( or process) keep running in foreground.

**Note 2:** an earlier version of your command `bash -c 'echo "hi"'` just print and since no other process running it is an exit. So, in order to keep running so need to write some commands to keep on running.

**Note 3:** For simplicity, I made to sleep for 30000.

Should solve your issue.